# Foreach returns only first record, stops

Tags: php, foreach

This should be very simple, but I'm getting odd behavior I've never seen before.  Here is the code:

```
<?php

$csv = array_map('str_getcsv',file('dummy.csv'));

$n=1;
foreach($csv as $key=>$val) {
      $sql = "UPDATE table set field = '$val[$key]' WHERE id = $n";
      echo $sql."\n";
      $n++;
}
?>
```

The .csv file is 260 simple text phrases that show up properly with `print_r($csv);`.  The above code gives proper output but stops after the first record.  Why?

Comment: Can you share the output of `print_r($csv);`, and enable error-reporting, then see if you get any errors?

Comment: Can you show what $csv has via var_export()?

Comment: Also a notable comment here on that snippet https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php#114764

Comment: Output of the print_r($csv):  Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => eros
            [1] => in
            [2] => cursus
            [3] => turpis
            [4] => massa
            [5] => tincidunt
            [6] => dui
            [7] => ut
            [8] => ornare
            [9] => lectus
            [10] => sit
... [259] => tempor

Comment: var_export($csv):  array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'eros',
    1 => 'in',
    2 => 'cursus',
    3 => 'turpis',
    4 => 'massa',
    5 => 'tincidunt',
    6 => 'dui',
    7 => 'ut',
    8 => 'ornare',
    9 => 'lectus',
    10 => 'sit',
...
259=>'tempor'

Comment: No errors were displayed using "E_ALL"

Comment: You array seems to have only one subarray. So this is the correct behaviour of the foreach loop.

Comment: In other words, you probably want `foreach ($csv[0] as $key=>$val) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str_getcsv` returns an array. 
`array_map` also returns an array.

So, your $csv is an array with an array within it. 
After your line `$csv = array_map('str_getcsv',file('dummy.csv'));`, add the line `$csv = $csv[0];` This pulls out the inner array. Then you should get the expected results without changing the remainder of your code.